# How to set multipath SVG as shape using CSS in JavaFX

Tags: css, svg, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have some button icons I would like to use in my application, such as a USB Icon, which contain multiple paths to define the SVG Shape.

For now I assign a region to the button graphics property, build a multi-path SVG using Java, then assign it as a shape to the region.

This is the current solution for multi-path icons (with Java):

```
SVGPath usb1 = new SVGPath();
usb1.setContent("M44,18H42V3a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H23a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V18H20a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V49a13,13,0,0,0,26,0V19A1,1,0,0,0,44,18ZM24,4H40V18H24ZM43,49a11,11,0,0,1-22,0V20H43Z");

SVGPath usb2 = new SVGPath();
usb2.setContent("M37,13H34a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V9a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h3a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v3A1,1,0,0,1,37,13Zm-2-2h1V10H35Z");

SVGPath usb3 = new SVGPath();
usb3.setContent("M30,13H27a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V9a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h3a1,1,0,0,1,1,1v3A1,1,0,0,1,30,13Zm-2-2h1V10H28Z");

SVGPath usb4 = new SVGPath();
usb4.setContent("M41,42a3,3,0,1,0-4,2.816v3.566l-4,2V29.414l2.293,2.293a1,1,0,0,0,1.414-1.414l-4-4a1,1,0,0,0-1.414,0l-4,4a1,1,0,0,0,1.414,1.414L31,29.414V44.382l-4-2V40h1a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V36a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H24a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v3a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h1v3a1,1,0,0,0,.553.9L31,46.618V55a1,1,0,0,0,2,0V52.618L38.447,49.9A1,1,0,0,0,39,49V44.816A3,3,0,0,0,41,42ZM25,37h2v1H25Zm13,6a1,1,0,1,1,1-1A1,1,0,0,1,38,43Z");

Shape s = Shape.union(Shape.union(usb1,usb2),Shape.union(usb3,usb4));
((Region) paramUsbButton.getGraphic()).setShape(s);
```

And for single path icons (with CSS):

```
.finished-button Region{
    -fx-background-color:black;
    -fx-shape:"M26,0C11.664,0,0,11.663,0,26s11.664,26,26,26s26-11.663,26-26S40.336,0,26,0z M40.495,17.329l-16,18 C24.101,35.772,23.552,36,22.999,36c-0.439,0-0.88-0.144-1.249-0.438l-10-8c-0.862-0.689-1.002-1.948-0.312-2.811 c0.689-0.863,1.949-1.003,2.811-0.313l8.517,6.813l14.739-16.581c0.732-0.826,1.998-0.9,2.823-0.166 C41.154,15.239,41.229,16.503,40.495,17.329z";
}
```

I would like to manage all icon shapes in CSS directly, is there a way to do this without having to use Java for multi-path SVGs?

Answer (score 1):

The `-fx-shape` property is not restricted to a single path. You can simply create the concatenation of the paths to get the union. You can easily get the union of the paths for use with the `-fx-shape` property in CSS this way.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // 2 seperate paths to combine
    String path1 = "M0,0h100v100h-100z";
    String path2 = "M100,0l50,50l-50,50z";

    Region region = new Region();
    region.setPrefSize(150, 100);
    region.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    region.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-shape: \""+ path1 + path2 + "\";");

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(region), 300, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The above example uses inline style for convenience, but you could easily achieve the same effect using the following stylesheet.

```
.root>Region {
    -fx-shape: "M0,0h100v100h-100zM100,0l50,50l-50,50z";
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Although I hadn't tried this before, the issue with this solution is that it makes the different paths of the icon not line up properly. I am not very familiar with how SVG paths work, but the concatenation does not seem to do it.

Comment: @base please provide a mcve for this issue (potentially asking a new question). I've just tested this out on your example and overlaying with blend mode difference leaves all the area of the shape black, even though the choice of background color was `red`. If there was a difference, the differing areas would contain a different color. `String p = Stream.of(usb1, usb2, usb3, usb4).map(SVGPath::getContent).collect(Collectors.joining()); region.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-shape: \""+ p + "\";");` This is not different from the union you used, if the dimensions of the regions match.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look here? https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg
According to the documentation this will also work via CSS.
I have no idea though whether this still works with JavaFX > 8.
If it does let me know and if not file an issue at GitHub :-)